# Windows Installer XML- Customising the msi UI

Tags: wix

How to customise the WiX UI? I need to remove the 'Cancel' button which appears in the Progress dialog box

Comment: https://www.firegiant.com/wix/tutorial/user-interface-revisited/

Answer (score 0):

A custom action will do that, scroll down here to the cusatom action part:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368791(v=vs.85).aspx

Session.Message if you use DTF type managed custom actions.